# How to make a display name for the sender in exchangelib for Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, email, label, exchangelib

I correctly send email messages with python exchangelib in this way:

```
   self.account = Account('myemail@domain.it', credentials=self.credentials, autodiscover=True)
   m = Message(account=self.account, folder=self.account.sent, subject=subject, body=body, to_recipients=to_recipients)
```

Now, I would like recipients to gets messages coming from 'label mailto:myemail@domain.it' but:

```
   self.account = Account('label <myemail@domain.it>', credentials=self.credentials, autodiscover=True)
```

doesn't work.
Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EWS supports customizing the label on the sender field. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/544